# Unable to run command without shell=True in subprocess command

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am developing a small tool with python in Linux. Earlier I was using Python 2.7 but now I changed it to Python 3.4 to see if it could help in solving my problem. When I am giving the following code:

```
try:
    x=subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True, timeout=3)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired as exc:
    print ("Timeout bro")
    exit()
except Exception as e:
    msg = "Some issues in fetching details"
    print (msg)
```

Since the command fetches details from another device and the device is not functioning properly, it is getting timed out after 3 secs and printing the message "Timeout bro". I read the security issues with using shell=True and therefore I made it shell=False for one time and for the second I removed that argument.

```
try:
    x=subprocess.check_output(command, shell=False, timeout=3)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired as exc:
    print ("Timeout bro")
    exit()
except Exception as e:
    msg = "Some issues in fetching details"
    print (msg)
```

I read at various places that the command works equally well with shell=False. But as soon as I run the above code with `shell=False` the code directly prints "Some issues in fetching details" without waiting for 3 secs. Is there any way through which I can run the code without shell=True? Please help. Thanks!

Comment: what is the command?

Comment: Also shell=False is the default so you don't need to pass it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try splitting the command with `command.split()`. A string will work in case of `shell=True` but for `shell=False` it expects a list of args. However, beware that split won't work in some cases like if you have space in a path etc. I suggest using `shlex` in that case.

Comment: Using `shlex` is definitely better for this, IMHO.

Answer (score 6):

When using `shell=True`, the `command` may be a string. When using `shell=False`, the `command` should be a list of strings, with the first string being the executable, and the subsequent strings being arguments to be passed to the executable.

You might try splitting the command with [`shlex.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#shlex.split):

```
import shlex
x = subprocess.check_output(shlex.split(command), shell=False, timeout=3)
```

By default, when `posix=True`, `shlex.split` drops backslashes. So if `shlex.split` does not work with your `command`, you may need to use `posix=False` or split the command manually.

Comment: Depending on where the command comes from, an even better solution is to build a list rather than a string in the first place. (How many hundreds of SO questions are about people doing 15 lines of string manipulation to build a command line to pass to `shlex.split` or directly to `check_output` and having some silly bug somewhere in those 15 lines that didn't have to be written in the first place?) But yeah, if what you've got to start with is a string, then `shlex` is definitely the way to go.